# Allow Remote Mysql To Centos Server

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a development server in my office, which runs through my domain server with routing.

Everything is fine, however i cannot connect to the development server mysql remotely.

The dev server is with ip 192.168.1.3 on the subnet in the office. I can ssh to it, reach apache and ftp. But mysql says: Host "192.168.1.2" is not allowed to connect to this MySql Server"

any help is appreciated. the ports are open on the firewall.

Comment: Possibly a security precaution. You could try adding a new administrator account:
for more details:
http://tiaashish.wordpress.com/2014/09/

Comment: sorry but that isn't helpful. I don't need permissions on the databases really because root has permissions on everything. I will only ever connect with the root user and this error is telling me that the mysql server itself is rejecting the connection before any authentication is done